# R package ebal for Entropy Balancing: Error message

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching, weighting, matchit, weightit

I use the R package **ebal** for calculation of weights between treatment group and control group.

The package version is

```
> packageVersion("ebal")
[1] ‘0.1.8’
```

After 21 iterations the process stopped with the following error message:

```
Iteration 1 maximum deviation is = 725,777,997 
new loss 368351536 old loss= 725777997 

Iteration 2 maximum deviation is = 368,351,536 
new loss 3.641804e+199 old loss= 368351536 
LS Step Length is  6.770353e-05 
Loss is 368360898 

...

Iteration 19 maximum deviation is = 211,453,719
new loss 615965613 old loss= 211453719 
LS Step Length is  0.001065976 
Loss is 211885123 

Iteration 20 maximum deviation is = 211,885,123 
new loss 394660098 old loss= 211885123 
LS Step Length is  0.000346154 
Loss is 212104989 

Iteration 21 maximum deviation is = 212,104,989 
new loss NaN old loss= 212104989 

Error in if (loss.old <= loss.new) { : 
    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I assume it has to do with the target means for the covariate distributions.
But I have no idea how to deal with it.
Could someone explain the error massage of *ebal*?

The doc [ebal: Entropy Reweighting to Create Balanced Samples](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ebal/ebal.pdf) doesn't contain any information about the errors.

Comment: maybe `survey::rake` can help you? See here for an [example](https://tophcito.blogspot.com/2014/04/survey-computing-your-own-post.html)

Comment: Don't use `ebal`. Use `WeightIt`, which was specifically designed to avoid this issue and yields as good if not better performance in general with a more straightforward interface.

Comment: You might try the new fork of that package, `remotes::install_github("apoorvalal/ebal")`.

Comment: @Noah This is not the finest way for a package author to draw attention to his own package, is it?

Comment: @Noah I'll test it. Is the following possible?
I do the following with ebal: The sample from the population is set as control group (tretment = 0). Then there is one row for the treatment group (treatment = 1). This row consists of all distributions of the population (first moments, seconds wouls also be possible). That is one individual with all characteristics of the population. After calulating the weights the sample with adjusted weights for the sample/control group is used as simulation for the population. It worked so far so good. But the last added variable led to the described error.

Comment: @Raidho yes that should work. It may be that your constraints are impossible to satisfy, but `weightit()` will tell you if that is the case.

Comment: Hello @Noah, thanks for your help. I had the first run with the WeightIt package and still have some questions. In ebal::ebalance() you can set the parameter norm.constant. I had a look at the WeightIt::weightit() documentation and didn't find it. Is there a possibility to do this? And the second question is: Which one of the estimands (ATE, ATT, ATC, ...) corresponds to the normal function of ebal::ebalance (for reproduction of my old results)?

Comment: `norm.constant` just multiplies the weights by a constant value, which doesn't change their properties at all (all estimates and measures of balance are independent of this value). You can just multiply the weights by whatever value you want, but there is no good reason to. In `weightit()`, the weights are scaled to have an average of 1 in each treatment group. You can request the same weights by setting `estimand = "ATT"`, which weights the control units to have the same covariate means as the treated units.

Comment: @Noah I set `norm.constant` to the population size with the result that the weights sum up approx. to the population size. And a covariate multiplied with it's weight and all summed up gives approx. the value of the population for that covariate (treatment group with one row). How is the mentioned factor calculated to do this with `weightit()`?

Comment: Divide the weights by the size of the treatment group and multiply them by the population size.

Comment: @Noah That doesn't give the expected result. Maybe I create a new question on this topic or could I write you a message?

Comment: Sure, you can write to the `WeightIt` [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/ngreifer/WeightIt/issues). It sounds like just using the version of `ebal` in the accepted answer will satisfy your requirements since you are not balancing treatment groups but rather trying to imitate the qualities of a population (with respect to size, not just covariate distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect either *loss.old* or *loss.new* becoming `NA` in line 40 of [`ebal::eb`](https://github.com/apoorvalal/ebal/blob/master/R/eb.R) which `ebal::ebalance` is using internally.

```
> loss.old <- 0
> loss.new <- NA
> if (loss.old <= loss.new) {}
Error in if (loss.old <= loss.new) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The author might have overseen that possibility and couldn't provide a better error message. Try make it reproducible an file an issue at their GitHub.

Comment: The package is no longer maintained and probably should not be used anymore. There is no link to report bugs and the package isn't on GitHub.

Comment: @Noah That's not entirely true, actually I've linked to it in my answer, it's a new version, maybe OP might try it.

Comment: Interesting, that version isn't on CRAN yet but looks promising. Still, I think there are other packages that work just as well and have a more friendly interface.